# Clone a file in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm having some problem with a linux module, I want to clone a file from a file descriptor. I tried using

```
vfs_clone_file_range
```

but i receive EOPNOTSUPP error. So I tried to use vfs_copy_file_range, and the copy works correctly, but I need to have also the same flags of the original one, but in this way, even if the original is open with O_APPEND the pointer of the copy is always at the begin of the file.

This is my code:

```
//The file descriptor is taken correctly and it works
original_filp = fcheck(o_fd);
copy_filp = filp_open(addr, O_CREAT | O_RDWR  , 0644);
vfs_copy_file_range(original_filp, 0, copy_filp, 0, i_size_read(original_filp->f_inode), 0);
```

The content is the right but the pointer, as I said is at the begin even with the O_APPEND flag, so I should move the pointer explicitly.
I also tried to add this line, but without results:

```
copy_filp->f_pos = original_filp->f_pos;
```

I really have no idea what to change in order to make it working.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe, because opening files is not what one should do in the kernel to begin with?

Comment: Maybe you don't know why and when I began? Probably an answer like "I don't know" would have been more useful. Thanks anyway for the information. I hope that someone that knows the answer will reply and I promise to test the code just on my virtual machine

Comment: So do you want to clone a **file descriptor** or clone(copy) **content** of the file? According to the signature and code, [vfs_clone_file_range](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c#L2069) copies content of the file, but doesn't create identical file descriptor.

Comment: I'm try to make a copy of the original file and then redirect the write to the copy. So I need a copy of the original one that is open with the same flags and mode. The problem occurs when I open with the O_APPEND flag, because the write starts always from the begin. Thank you for your attention

Comment: "The problem occurs when I open with the O_APPEND flag, because the write starts always from the begin." - Are you sure that the write **actually** starts from the beginning of the file? The flag `O_APPEND` means that **on every write** the position in the file is adjusted to the end of the file, so the position before the write doesn't matter.

Comment: I need to have the same flags of the original file, so, for example if o_fd is the file descriptor of a file opened with O_APPEND flag, I need that copy_filp is opened with the same flag, and every vfs_write called onto the copy_filp should start from the end. Everything works well without O_APPEND, the only thing I thought was to change f_pos, but it didn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get it, but according with the documentation, the copy_file_range returns EBADF error code when the file_out has the O_APPEND set. So a way to solve can be:

```
//The file descriptor is taken correctly and it works
original_filp = fcheck(o_fd);
copy_filp = filp_open(addr, O_CREAT | O_RDWR  , 0644);
vfs_copy_file_range(original_filp, 0, copy_filp, 0, `i_size_read(original_filp->f_inode), 0);`
copy_filp->f_flags=original_filp->f_flags
```

In this way you have the same flags set on the two files

Comment: Yep! It was what I needed, Thank you!